# CSS text animation independent of font-size and number of list items

Tags: html, css

I've come across an interesting animation which loops through words in a list and only displays one of them at any given time.  You can see the original here: https://codepen.io/yoannhel/pen/sJpDj .

Stripping off everything not related to the animation we are left with the following HTML and CSS:

```css
    .visible {
      font-weight:600;
      overflow:hidden;
      height:40px;
      padding:0 40px;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin-top:0;
      padding-left:110px;
      text-align:left;
      list-style:none;
      -webkit-animation-name: change;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-name: change;
      animation-duration: 6s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    ul li {
      line-height:40px;
      margin:0;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes change {
      0%, 12%, 100% {transform:translateY(0);}
      17%,29% {transform:translateY(-25%);}
      34%,46% {transform:translateY(-50%);}
      51%,63% {transform:translateY(-75%);}
      68%,80% {transform:translateY(-50%);}
      85%,97% {transform:translateY(-25%);}
    }
    
    @keyframes change {
      0%, 12%, 100% {transform:translateY(0);}
      17%,29% {transform:translateY(-25%);}
      34%,46% {transform:translateY(-50%);}
      51%,63% {transform:translateY(-75%);}
      68%,80% {transform:translateY(-50%);}
      85%,97% {transform:translateY(-25%);}
    }
```

```html
    <div class='visible'>
        <ul>
          <li>world !</li>
          <li>Bob !</li>
          <li>users !</li>
          <li>everybody !</li>
           <li>Stack Overflow !</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Because most values in the CSS are hard-coded, adding an extra item to the `ul` list, for example, already breaks the animation (as shown in snippet above).

I've tried fiddling around with values, but as a beginner I haven't figured out yet the interrelation between all parameters. It seems like changing the font-size requires changing the height of `.visible` and the `line-height` of the `li` elements; and changing the number of items in the list requires direct changes on the animation `change`.

I want to achieve the same effect, but independent of font-size and number of items in the list (I'm not so worried about screen-size, though it would be cool to have it work in narrow screens too). Does anyone have an idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

look at [this demo](https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/jrrPpW) - variant with pixels may be clearer.

Percentage in animation is 100% roughly divided by 6 (we have 6 items)

Yoffset = -20px * number of item (first two stages are zero to have delay)

```css
.frame {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 20px;
}

.slot-machine {
  animation: roll-up-out 6s ease 0s infinite alternate;
  margin: 0px;
}
.slot-machine li {
  height: 20px;
}

@keyframes roll-up-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  16% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  32% {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  48% {
    transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  64% {
    transform: translateY(-60px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <ul class="slot-machine">
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
    <li>ddd</li>
    <li>eee</li>
    <li>fff</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it still has problems if I change the number of items or the font-size. Ideally the slot-machine would have to adapt the translation according to the number of children in `ul`, I guess...

Comment: I don't see any way to consider number of list items without javascript. As an option you can predefine such animation classes for different number of items and set correct class on backend or by js. In my version it depends on height of li item, not on font size.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Unfortunately my use case doesn't allow JS for security reasons. Though the hard-coded solution works, it isn't flexible when I want to reuse it.